# JSON select from array

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON object:

```
[{"_id":"57b1f03ec4f37923cc436100","pokedex_id":134,"location":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-117.4955084,34.0175467]}},
{"_id":"57b1f03fc4f37923cc436101","pokedex_id":134,"location":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-117.4955084,34.0175467]}}]
```

I'm trying to access the data with `console.log(temp[0]);`, but for some reason my output is just `[`. What am I doing wrong? Also, any subsequent index just seems to return the corresponding char value. For example: `temp[1]` returns `{`, `temp[3]` returns `_`.

Comment: what is `temp`? can you paste the whole code?

Comment: I think Temp is JSON Object name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JavaScript, [there is no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

You have a JSON text, which is a string.

`somestring[0]` gives you the first character of that string.

[Use `JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to convert your JSON text into a JavaScript array.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

It's because it's stringified right now.

Accessing `'somestring'[0]` will give you the first character of the string.

To cast your JSON string to a plain old JavaScript object, you should do

```
var actualArray = JSON.parse(temp);
```

Then, `actualArray[0]` will give you the first item in the array.

Answer (score -1):

Another way is to parse your JSON file into a string, and retrieve the values.

```
String JSONFileString = File.ReadAllText("yourFile.json");

JavaScriptSerializer slizer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

ObjectName o1 = slizer.Deserialize<ObjectName>(JSONString);

Console.Writeline(o1);
```